# Returning a value and using it as a parameter

Tags: java

So, the program I am working on is one that asks a user for todays date and tells them what absolute day of the year it is. The program then asks the user for the date of their birthday, and using the value for today's absolute day that it got from the previous method, tells the user how many days it is until their next birthday. I have the first part down, but am struggling with the second. here is my expected output:

Please enter today's date:

What is the month (1-12)? 7

What is the day   (1-31)? 24

7/24 is day #205 of 365.

Please enter your birthday:

What is the month (1-12)? 11

What is the day   (1-30)? 6

11/6 is day #310 of 365.

Your next birthday is in 105 days.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Birthday
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   introduction();
   absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console);
   nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer(console, todayAbsoluteDay); 
   }

   public static void introduction()
   {
      System.out.print("This program tells you how manys days\n");
      System.out.println("it will be until your next birthday.");
   }

   public static int absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(Scanner console)
   {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Please enter today's date:");



      System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");     
      int currentMonth = console.nextInt();

      System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
      int currentDay = console.nextInt();

      int todayAbsoluteDay = findAbsoluteDay(currentMonth, currentDay);

      System.out.print(currentMonth + "/" + currentDay + " is day #" + 
      todayAbsoluteDay + " of 365");

      return todayAbsoluteDay;     
   }

   public static int findAbsoluteDay(int currentMonth, int currentDay)
   {
       int days = 0;
           for (int i = 1; i < currentMonth; i++)
           {
               days += daysInMonth(i);  
           }
           days += currentDay;
    return days;
   }

   public static int daysInMonth(int month)
   {
       if (month == 2)
       {
           return 28;
       }
       else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
       {
           return 30;
       }
       else
       {
           return 31;
       }
   }

   public static void nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer(Scanner console, int todayAbsoluteDay)
   {
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Please enter your birthday:");

  System.out.print("What is the month (1-12)? ");
  int birthdayMonth = console.nextInt();

  System.out.print("What is the day   (1-31)? ");
  int birthdayDay = console.nextInt();

  int birthdayAbsoluteDay = findAbsoluteDay(birthdayMonth, birthdayDay);

  System.out.print("your next birthday is in " + 
  compare(birthdayAbsoluteDay, todayAbsoluteDay) + " days.");
  }

  public static int compare(int birthday, int today)
  {
      if (birthday > today)
      {
          return birthday - today;
      }
      else if (birthday < today)
      {
          return (365 - today) + birthday;
      }
      else
      {
          return 0;
      }    
  } 
}
```

This is my current code. In my `absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer` method,  I am returning todays absolute day, and am trying to use that value as a parameter and put it in my `nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer` method, which I call from main method. However, this isn't working, and I am struggling to find a reason why. I am getting a cannot find symbol error. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of solving your problem:

Where you have the line in your main method:

```
absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console);
```

You need to assign this value to an Integer.

```
int todayAbsoluteDay = absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console);
```

Then run the code again and see what happens.

Your `absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer` method is returning an `int` `todayAbsoluteDay`. However, you did not assign this to an `int` in your main method and you cannot pass this value through to your `nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer` method without doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the value returned from the first method to the second one, just change your main like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    introduction();
    nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer(console, absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console)); 
}
```

Comment: This code definitely works and is more concise than my answer's version. However, I think my answer's code is clearer to comprehend for the level of programming required to write this.

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not know, that if a method returns a value, you can store the return value in a variable by using this syntax:

```
<variable name> = <method call>;
```

So your code should be:

```
int todayAbsoluteDay = absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console);
nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer(console, todayAbsoluteDay);
```

If you are confused, think of it this way,

When you use the syntax mentioned above, the method is "replaced" by its return value after evaluation:

```
myVar = someMethod(); // someMethod always returns 1
```

turns into:

```
myVar = 1;
```

Since the method is "replaced" by its return value after evaluation, you can also write the whole thing in one line:

```
nextBirthdayPromptAndAnswer(console, absoluteDayPromptAndAnswer(console));
```

But I think it's less readable this way.